# Array.indexOf always returns -1 when search for array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-lists

I have an array of arrays:

```
var BigArray = [[1,2,3,"Foo"],[4,5,6,"Bar"], [1,2,3,"Baz"]];
```

I want to find the index of, say, `[1,2,3,"Foo"]`. When I do `console.log(BigArray.indexOf([1,2,3,"Foo"]))`, it always returns `-1`, even though `[1,2,3,"Foo"]` does exist inside `BigArray`. Is there a fix to this?

Comment: If below answers are useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If any answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You are using an array to find another array when attempting to use `indexOf` this does not work that way, you have to use a scalar value.

You can use a simple for loop to accomplish what you intend.

```
const BigArray = [[1,2,3,"Foo"],[4,5,6,"Bar"], [1,2,3,"Baz"]];
let i;
let index = -1;

for(i = 0; i < BigArray.length; i++) {
    if(BigArray[i].includes('Foo')) {
        index = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it *without* having to use an external library:

```js
const BigArray = [[1,2,3,"Foo"],[4,5,6,"Bar"], [1,2,3,"Baz"]],
      lookFor=[4,5,6,"Bar"];

// the comparison === between two objects will only be true
// if these are the same objects (ONE and the same!)
// === will NOT compare their contents!

console.log(BigArray.indexOf(lookFor)) // -1

// if you want to compare their contents you could convert
// them to JSOn representations:

console.log(BigArray.map(JSON.stringify).indexOf(JSON.stringify(lookFor))) // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> `indexOf()` compares `searchElement` to elements of the Array using [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) (the same method used by the `===` or triple-equals operator).

And, strict equality produces `false` for different objects (even when their values are same) because it checks against **values** for [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) (except [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol)) and **object references** for objects.

[Example:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality#comparing_objects)

```js
console.log("hello" === "hello"); // true

const object1 = { name: "hello" };
const object2 = { name: "hello" };

console.log(object1 === object2); // false
console.log(object1 === object1); // true
```

Hence, you can not solve your current problem using `Array.prototype.indexOf()`, but you can use `findIndex` and `isEqual` methods from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) (you may also try [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/)):

**Using lodash:**

```js
var BigArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, "Foo"],
  [4, 5, 6, "Bar"],
  [1, 2, 3, "Baz"]
];

console.log(_.findIndex(BigArray, function(o) {
  return _.isEqual(o, [4, 5, 6, "Bar"]);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```